# Write complex number $z^5$ in the form $r(\cos θ + i\sin θ)$

Tags: complex-numbers

Let $z = 4(\cos \frac 8 7 π + i\sin\frac 8 7π)$ be a complex number. Find $z^5$ in the form $r(\cos θ + i\sin θ)$ with r being a positive real number, and with  $0 ≤ θ < 2π$.

My attempt:  $z^5 = 1024(\cos \frac 8 7 π + i\sin\frac 8 7π)$

I feel this I've done something wrong; that there should be more steps to this. I'm not familiar with complex numbers so any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Problem looks familiar. Did you get that off an old exam of mine?

Comment: Pretty simple: $z = 4e^{\frac{8\pi}{7}}$ so $z^5 = 4^5e^{\frac{40\pi}{7}}$.  But $\frac{40}{7} = 5 + \frac{5}{7}$ meaning that $z^5 = 1024\left(\cos\left(\frac{12\pi}{7}\right) + i\sin\left(\frac{12\pi}{7}\right)\right)$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Must be, it is from a past paper from macq uni.

Comment: @Jared I am a bit confused. What is the 'e' in this example?

Comment: [De Moivre's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre%27s_formula) might help.

Comment: @Trigamatuer well $e$ is [$e$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_(mathematical_constant)).  I did mess up and forgot to put $z = 4e^{\frac{8\pi}{7}i}$ and, in the final result: $z^5 = 1024e^{\frac{12\pi}{7}i}$  because $\frac{40}{7} = \frac{4\cdot 7 + 12}{7} = 4 + \frac{12}{7}$.  We could have just as easily said that $\frac{40}{7} = \frac{42}{7} - \frac{2}{7}$ and thus $z^5 = 1024e^{-\frac{2}{7}i}$

Comment: @MartinSleziak That helps tremendously. Thanks.

Comment: @Jared How did you turn $40/7$ into $2/7$?

Comment: @Trigamatuer Because $\frac{40}{7} = 5 + \frac{5}{7}$.  We need this in terms of multiples of $2$ (so that we have $2\pi$--everything here is multiplied by $\pi$).  Either we have $\frac{40}{7} = 4 + \frac{12}{7}$ or $\frac{40}{7} = 6 - \frac{2}{7}$.  Either way it's added or subtracted from $2$--really $2\pi$.

Comment: @Jared Right that makes sense. Thanks very much!